# Restart a python function in a script after n minutes

Tags: python, server-sent-events

I have a script that uses a server-sent event library to connect with a server that pushes events to me regularly. The issue is that the stream will freeze after a long time and I will have to restart the script manually and this is not maintainable. The structure of the current code looks like this

```
def listen(self):
        print("listening to events .....")
        try:
            url = settings.EVENT_URL + "/v1/events"
            auth_key = settings.KEY

            headers = {
                "Authorization": "Basic " + auth_key,
                "Accept": "text/event-stream",
            }

            response = self.with_urllib3(url, headers)
            client = sseclient.SSEClient(response)

            for event in client.events():
                # the script freezes here.
                logger.info(event.data)

                process(event.data)
```

I have tried doing something like

```
def start(self):
    def wait():
        time.sleep(10 * 60)

    background = threading.Thread(name = 'background', target = self.listen)
    background.daemon = True
    background.start()
    wait()

try:
    self.start()
except:
    self.start()
finally:
    self.start()
```

But I don't know if this will work mainly because a daemon thread will keep running in the background which means I will have copies of the task running after a while.

What I need is a better way to call a function and after some elapsed time return from the function and recall it again immediately. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider a construction using the `signal` module like shown below. As a note though, the `SIGALRM` signal is not compatible with Windows.

```py
import signal


TIMEOUT = 5


def _handle_alarm(_, __):
    raise TimeoutError("Some useful message")


def listen():
    print("Starting to listen...")
    import time
    time.sleep(10)


while True:
    try:
        timer = signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, _handle_alarm)
        timer.alarm(TIMEOUT)
        listen()
    except TimeoutError:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What happens if the call to listen() returns early due to an exception and the while True block creates another new instance of the alarm? Will the old alarm fire even after the code is in a new session? Thanks

Comment: In the example snippet ideally any exception raised from within listen is not caught (raising a custom exception would not be a bad idea), so the program would terminate. You could catch, say, a connection error in a separate except block. In this case you can defuse the alarm in this block, which seems to be done by calling `timer.alarm(0)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. signal.alarm(0) works for me.